# Why am I getting permission denied error?

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-12.04

I am tryng to create a symlink but I am getting permission denied. How do I tell why?

```
ln -nfs /home/deploy/foo/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo': Permission denied
```

This is the content of my `visudo` file:

```
# This file is managed by Chef.
# Do NOT modify this file directly.

Defaults      !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn

# User privilege specification
root          ALL=(ALL) ALL

deploy ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the group 'sysadmin' may gain root privileges
%sysadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL
# Members of the group 'sysadmins' may gain root privileges
%sysadmins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I am logged in as a user called deploy, I am inside the `sysadmins` group.

```
whoami
deploy

cat /etc/group
deploy:x:1000:
sysadmin:x:2300:deploy
```

Comment: What command did you run? What is the output of `id`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, a bit stupid of me not to include the command. I updated the question. I also don't know what you mean by `output of id`--I'm a novice at this.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ln ...` ?

Comment: @krisFR if I use sudo it works. But I am using Capistrano 3 which can't execute sudo commands.

Comment: That means you type in `id` and press Enter. Then you paste the output.

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK. Here is the output `gid=1000(deploy) groups=1000(deploy),2300(sysadmin)`

Comment: Um, wait, if you don't use `sudo` then it's not going anywhere. In any event you don't have to do this in your deployment anyway; it's a one time thing.

Comment: don't know Capistrano 3. Try this before running the `ln` command : `chmod o+w /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we discussed in comments :

You should run your `ln` command using `sudo` :

```
sudo ln -nfs /home/deploy/foo/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo
```

Now, if this is not possible because of Capistrano 3 (which i don't know), you have to give your `deploy` user write permissions on folder `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I tried originally. It craps out: `sudo no tty present and no askpass program specified`. I'm going to try your other suggestion.

Comment: @Jumbalaya Wanton What about now ?

Answer (score 4):

Having permission to use sudo does not automatically run all your commands as root.  That would eliminate all the security benefits of bot using the root account directly.

You need to run the command through sudo, or change permissions so your regular user account can write there.